# How to add minutes to a time string?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using momentjs to manipulate time. I have an hour, minute, second string like '00:30:00'. And I want to add few mins to it. With momentjs I can convert this string into minutes then I can easily add the minutes I want. But how do I make it back to the sting?

ex - moment.duration('00:30:00').asMinutes; will give me minutes.
Suppose this give 30 , I can add 30 more mins to it to make it 60mins.
how do I convert 60mins to this string again using momentjs?

On printing

```
console.log(moment.duration('00:30:00').add(30, 'minutes'));
```

I am getting

```
[object Object] { _bubble: function Zc(){var    a,b,c,d,e,f=this._milliseconds,g=this._days,h=this._months,i=this._data;
// if we have a mix of positive and negative values, bubble down first
// check: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2166
// The following code bubbles up values, see the tests for
// examples of what that means.
// convert days to months
// 12 months -> 1 year
return f>=0&&g>=0&&h>=0||0>=f&&0>=g&&0>=h||(f+=864e5*Yc(_c(h)+g),g=0,h=0),i.milliseconds=f%1e3,a=s(f/1e3),i.seconds=a%60,b=s(a/60),i.minutes=b%60,c=s(b/60),i.hours=c%24,g+=s(c/24),e=s($c(g)),h+=e,g-=Yc(_c(e)),d=s(h/12),h%=12,i.days=g,i.months=h,i.years=d,this},
  .... continued
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use [`.add`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/add/).

```
moment.duration('00:30:00').add(30, 'minutes);
```

Then you can run `.asMinutes` on that to print the total duration.

```
moment.duration('00:30:00').add(30, 'minutes').asMinutes();
```

You want to always use `.asMinutes` last, only when you want to pull the total minutes.

Comment: It's giving me something else. Can u try it once

Comment: @scripter Please edit your question with what you tried and the entire error message.

Comment: @bevacqua I got it. What if I want to covert it back to String into '00:30:00' format?

Comment: @scripter You could just do `moment(30, 'mm').format('HH:mm:ss')`

Answer (score -1):

You can work around this behavior by cloning the moment, [as described here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/).

```
var timestring1 = "2016-05-09T00:00:00Z";
var timestring2 = "2016-05-09T02:00:00Z";
var startdate = moment(timestring1);
var expected_enddate = moment(timestring2);
var returned_endate = moment(startdate).add(30, 'minutes');  // see the cloning?
returned_endate.isSame(expected_enddate)  // true
```

Comment: I want to convert minutes  into the string like this '00:30:00'.